# Comparing two files, where one piece of information can be flexible

Tags: perl

Comparing two files. So easy, but comparing two files where one piece of information can be flexible is proving to be very challenging for me.

```
fileA 
4 "dup" 37036335 37044984   
3 "dup" 100146708 100147504 
7 "del" 100 203
2 "dup" 34 89

fileB
4 "dup" 37036335 37036735
3 "dup" 100146708 100147504
4 "dup" 68 109
```

Anticipated output:

```
output_file1 (matching hits)
fileA: 4 "dup" 37036335 37044984
fileB: 4 "dup" 37036335 37036735

fileA: 3 "dup" 100146708 100147504
fileB: 3 "dup" 100146708 100147504

output_file2 (found in fileA, but not in FileB including non-overlap)
7 "del" 100 203
2 "dup" 34 89

output_file3 (found in fileB, but not in FileA including non-overlap)
4 "dup" 68 109
```

The credentials are...
I need field 1 and field 2 in the first file to exactly match the second file and the coordinates in field 3 to be exact or overlap.

```
This would mean these are the same.
fileA :4 "dup" 37036335 37044984 
fileB :4 "dup" 37036335 37036735
```

I also need to find differences between the two files. (no-overlap, 1 row isn't present in one file, but not in the other, etc)

Here's the gist of what I've tried. I've written this code probably 4 different ways, alas, still no success. I've put both files into arrays (I've tried a hash too...idk)

```
## if no hits in original, but hits in calculated
   if((! @ori) && (@calc)){}

## if CNV calls in original, but none in calculated
   if((@ori) && (! @calc)){}

## if CNV calls in both
   if((@ori) && (@calc)){

         ## compare calls with double 'for' loop
         foreach my $l (@ori){

                my @l = split(/\s/,$l);
                my $Ochromosome = $l[0];
                my $Ostart = $l[2];
                my $Oend = $l[3];
                my $Otype = $l[1];

                foreach my $l (@calc){

                       my @l = split(/\s/,$l);
                       my $Cchromosome = $l[0];
                       my $Cstart = $l[2];
                       my $Cend = $l[3];
                       my $Ctype = $l[1];

                       ## check chromosome and type here
                     if(($Ochromosome eq $Cchromosome) && ($Otype eq $Ctype)){ ## what if there are two duplications on the same chromosome?
                             ## check coordinates
                             if(($Ostart <= $Cend) && ($Cstart <= $Oend)){
                                  ## overlap
                              }else{
                                  ## noOverlap
                              }                                       
                       }else{
                         ## what if there is something found in one, but not in the other and they both have calls?
                         ## ahhhh
                                        }                               
                                }
                        }
```

Comment: That second 4 "dup" line in file B is another wrench in my series of problems. I just posted the anticipated output. Thanks.

Comment: These files are not sorted in any way and their lines may be mixed around, right?  (So line #2 from fileA may match line #50 from fileB.)  Are the files very large?  What do you mean by "_the coordinates in field 3 to be exact **or overlap**_" -- how does the number in field 3 "_overlap_"?

Comment: Not sorted at all.  I meant the range from fields 3 and 4. The logic is more explicit.

Comment: OK.  So, `10 20` and `18 30` "match" but `10 20` and `21 30` don't, right?  Also: are the files very very large?

Comment: No. 10 20 is exactly like 10 20. 10 18 and 10 20 overlap. 10 20 and 21 31 don't over lap.

Comment: Well, OK -- but do you need to make a distinction between fields 3 and 4 being exactly the same or overlapping?  (As long as third is the same, I forgot that.  Lotsa rules :).  If they are _either_ exactly the same _or_ overlap the lines are considered to match, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution which is also fairly efficient.

Iterate over lines of one file, checking each against all lines of the other (until a match is found). This is the very least we must do complexity wise, given all information that needs to be gathered.

If a line from `A` is not found in `B`, it is added to `@not_in_B`.  To determine which lines in `B` are not in `A`, we prepare a hash where each element of `B` is a key with a value `0`. Once/if an element of `B` is found, the value of its key in the hash is set to `1`. Those that are not `1` at the end have never been found by elements of `A`, and so are the extra ones. They go in `@not_in_A`.

Both files are first read into arrays for simplicity (but this *is* needed for the inner loop).

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $f1 = 'f1.txt';
my $f2 = 'f2.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $f1;
my @a1 = <$fh>; chomp(@a1);
open $fh, '<', $f2;
my @a2 = <$fh>; chomp(@a2);
close $fh;

my (@not_in_A, @not_in_B);
my %Bs_in_A = map { $_ => 0 } @a2;

foreach my $e1 (@a1)
{
    my $match = 0;
    foreach my $e2 (@a2) 
    {
        if ( lines_match($e1, $e2) ) { 
            $match = 1;
            say "Match:\n\tf1: $e1\n\tf2: $e2";
            $Bs_in_A{$e2} = 1;
            last;
        }
    }   
    push @not_in_B, $e1 if not $match;
}
@not_in_A = grep { $Bs_in_A{$_} == 0 } keys %Bs_in_A;

say '---';    
say "Elements of A that are not in B:";
say "\t$_" for @not_in_B;
say "Elements of B that are not in A:";
say "\t$_" for @not_in_A;


sub lines_match
{
    my ($l1, $l2) = @_; 
    my @t1 = split ' ', $l1;
    my @t2 = split ' ', $l2;

    # First two fields must be the same
    return if $t1[0] ne $t2[0] or $t1[1] ne $t2[1];

    # Third-to-fourth-field ranges must overlap
    return
        if ($t1[2] < $t2[2] and $t1[3] < $t2[2])
        or ($t1[2] > $t2[3] and $t1[3] > $t2[3]);

    return 1;  # match
}
```

Output

```
Match:
        f1: 4 "dup" 37036335 37044984   
        f2: 4 "dup" 37036335 37036735
Match:
        f1: 3 "dup" 100146708 100147504 
        f2: 3 "dup" 100146708 100147504
---
Elements of A that are not in B:
        7 "del" 100 203
        2 "dup" 34 89
Elements of B that are not in A:
        4 "dup" 68 109
```

Note that I've used `1` in place of `A` and `2` in place of `B`.

Comment: @user1807271  Here is a basic solution, tested with your sample data.  Let me know whether it matches the requirements.  The criterion for how the third and fourth fields should be compared is tucked away in a sub so it can be adjusted if I misunderstood it.  The key trick is the hash that records all elements of B that _have been_ found -- so the remaining ones (with value 0 in the hash) are the extra ones in B.

Comment: It looks good! The only thing missing (piece I need), is if it doesn't overlap then it needs to be put in \@not_in_A or \@not_in_B. Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't think I mentioned that issue above.

Comment: @user1807271  It _is_ put there.  If it doesn't overlap (the last, long, condition in the function) then the function returns false (lines don't match). Then that goes into `@not_in_B`.  All elements of `B` which were never matched by anything never got the `1` in the hash so they go into `@not_in_A` in the end.  It should take care of all cases.  It should be tested on bigger (and more varied) samples but it should be fine.  I think that the output fits the data, and matches what you show.

Comment: Ah. I missed it. I'm going to give it a go today! Thanks. I will let you know what happens.

Comment: worked like a charm! (I had to edit the subroutine to better fit our definition of overlap) Really appreciate the help.

Comment: @user1807271 Great :)  That's what functions (and modular approaches) are for, it's much easier to tweak and change things. Btw, this should be fairly efficient, too. Let me know if any follow-up questions come up.